# Access ArrayList from another class without having to change the methods and variables to static, unless this is not an issue

Tags: java

I am a complete novice to programming in Java and have been struggling with a semester assignment. Amongst other things, I have had problems creating an ArrayList in one class and accessing it in another as an information basis to do further tasks. Below there is the problem I have been having. If anyone is also interested in helping develop the algorithm for the project with me as a side project just let me know ;)

Here is the class where the ArrayList holzZuschnittRessource should be created:

```java
public class Verarbeitung {

    private ArrayList<Auftrag> auftraegeBearbeitung = new ArrayList<Auftrag>();
    public ArrayList<Holz> holzZuschnittRessource = new ArrayList<Holz>();
    public ArrayList<Holz> holzZuschnittAuftrag = new ArrayList<Holz>();
    private Ressourcendatei ressourcendatei;
    private Auftragsdatei auftragsdatei;

    public Verarbeitung(Ressourcendatei ressourcendatei, Auftragsdatei auftragsdatei) {
        this.ressourcendatei = ressourcendatei;
        this.auftragsdatei = auftragsdatei;
        this.auftragswahl();

    }

    private void auftragswahl() {

        for (int i = 0; i < auftragsdatei.getAuftraege().size(); i++) {

            Auftrag auftrag = auftragsdatei.getAuftraege().get(i);

            ArrayList<Scharnier> scharniereauftrag = new ArrayList<Scharnier>();
            scharniereauftrag = auftrag.getScharniere();
            boolean scharnierVorhanden = false;
            HashMap<String, Scharnier> scharniereressource = ressourcendatei.getScharniere();

            if (scharniereauftrag.size() != 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < scharniereauftrag.size(); j++) {

                    for (Entry<String, Scharnier> scharnier : scharniereressource.entrySet()) {
                        // for (int k = 0; k < scharniereressource.size(); k++) {

                        if (scharniereauftrag.get(j).getKennung().equals(scharnier.getValue().getKennung())
                                && scharniereauftrag.get(j).getAnzahl() <= scharnier.getValue().getAnzahl()) {
                            // if
                            // (scharniereauftrag.get(j).getKennung().equals(scharniereressource.get(k).getKennung())
                            // && scharniereauftrag.get(j).getAnzahl() <=
                            // scharniereressource.get(k).getAnzahl()) {
                            scharnierVorhanden = true;
                        }

                    }
                }
            } else {
                scharnierVorhanden = true;
            }

            ArrayList<Schiene> schienenauftrag = new ArrayList<Schiene>();
            schienenauftrag = auftrag.getSchienen();
            boolean schieneVorhanden = false;
            HashMap<String, Schiene> schienenressource = ressourcendatei.getSchienen();
            if (schienenauftrag.size() != 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < schienenauftrag.size(); j++) {

                    for (Entry<String, Schiene> schiene : schienenressource.entrySet()) {

                        if (schienenauftrag.get(j).getLaenge() >= schiene.getValue().getLaengeMin()
                                && schienenauftrag.get(j).getLaenge() <= schiene.getValue().getLaengeMax()) {
                            schieneVorhanden = true;
                        }

                    }

                    /*
                     * for (int k = 0; k < schienenressource.size(); k++) {
                     * 
                     * if (schienenauftrag.get(j).getLaenge() >=
                     * schienenressource.get(k).getLaengeMin() && schienenauftrag.get(j).getLaenge()
                     * <= schienenressource.get(k).getLaengeMax()) { schieneVorhanden = true; }
                     * 
                     * }
                     */
                }
            } else {
                schieneVorhanden = true;
            }

            ArrayList<Holz> holzauftrag = new ArrayList<Holz>();
            holzauftrag = auftrag.getBretter();
            boolean holzVorhanden = false;

            if (holzauftrag.size() != 0) {

                for (int j = 0; j < holzauftrag.size(); j++) {
                    HashMap<String, Holz> holzressource = ressourcendatei.getBretter();

                    for (Entry<String, Holz> holz : holzressource.entrySet()) {

                        if (holzauftrag.get(j).getKennung().equals(holz.getValue().getKennung())) {
                            if (holzauftrag.get(j).getStaerke() == holz.getValue().getStaerke()) {
                                if (holzauftrag.get(j).getBreite() <= holz.getValue().getBreite() - 2) {
                                    if (holzauftrag.get(j).getHoehe() <= holz.getValue().getHoehe() - 2) {
                                        if (holzauftrag.get(j).getAnzahl() <= holz.getValue().getAnzahl()) {

                                            holzVorhanden = true;
                                            if (scharnierVorhanden == true && schieneVorhanden == true) {
                                                
                                                this.holzZuschnittRessource.add(holz.getValue());
                                                this.holzZuschnittAuftrag.add(holzauftrag.get(j));

                                                holz.getValue().subtrahiereAnzahl(holzauftrag.get(j).getAnzahl());

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                holzVorhanden = true;
            }

            if (scharnierVorhanden == true && schieneVorhanden == true && holzVorhanden == true) {

                for (int j = 0; j < scharniereauftrag.size(); j++) {
                    for (Entry<String, Scharnier> scharnier : scharniereressource.entrySet()) {

                        if (scharniereauftrag.get(j).getKennung().equals(scharnier.getValue().getKennung())) {

                            scharnier.getValue().subtrahiereAnzahl(scharniereauftrag.get(j).getAnzahl());
                        }

                    }

                }

                for (int j = 0; j < schienenauftrag.size(); j++) {
                    for (Entry<String, Schiene> schiene : schienenressource.entrySet()) {

                        if (schienenauftrag.get(j).getKennung().equals(schiene.getValue().getKennung())) {

                            schiene.getValue().subtrahiereAnzahl(schienenauftrag.get(j).getAnzahl());
                        }

                    }

                }

                this.auftraegeBearbeitung.add(auftrag);

            }

        }
    }
    public ArrayList<Holz> getHolzZuschnittRessource () {
        auftragswahl();
        ArrayList<Holz> holzZuschnittRessource2 = holzZuschnittRessource;
        return holzZuschnittRessource2;
    }
    
    public ArrayList<Holz> getHolzZuschnittAuftrag () {
        auftragswahl();
        ArrayList<Holz> holzZuschnittRessource2 = holzZuschnittRessource;
        return holzZuschnittRessource2;
    }

}
```

And here the class where the ArrayList *holzZuschnittRessource* should be accessed:

```java
 public class Zuschnitt {   
    ArrayList<Holz> auftraege = Verarbeitung.getHolzZuschnittAuftrag();
    ArrayList<Holz> ressourcen = Verarbeitung.getHolz();
    
    
    
    //Mit 1cm verschenktes Material an den Aussenraendern rechnen
    public ArrayList<Holz> Aussenrand (ArrayList <Holz> ressourcenListe) {
        for (Holz ressource : ressourcenListe) {
            ressource.setBreite(ressource.getBreite() - 2);
            ressource.setHoehe(ressource.getHoehe() - 2);
        }
        return ressourcenListe;  
    }
    
    public boolean MinZuschnittsgroesse () {
        for (Holz auftrag : auftraege) {
            if (auftrag.getBreite() < minZuschnittsgroesse || auftrag.getHoehe() < minZuschnittsgroesse) {
                System.out.println("Zuschnittgroesse in " + auftrag + "zu klein fuer Maschine"); //TODO: spaeter Dialogfeld und entscheiden wie es weiter macht wenn zu klein
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    public void FraeseBeladen () {
        standbyModus = true;
        }
    
    public Zuschnitt (ArrayList<Holz> auftraege, ArrayList<Holz> ressourcen, int gefahreneStrecke) {
        //hier spaeter pruefen ob es sich um Holz handelt, z.B. if (auftrag startsWith(Holz.KEYWORD))
        FraeseBeladen ();   //TODO: ueberlegen wie Verarbeitungsdatei einbinden
        for (Holz auftrag : auftraege) {
        for (Holz ressource : Aussenrand(ressourcen)) {
            //zuerst wird nach eine passende Holzplatte gesucht 
            if (auftrag.getBreite() <= ressource.getBreite() && auftrag.getHoehe() <= ressource.getHoehe()
                    && ressource.getAnzahl() > 0 && MinZuschnittsgroesse()) {
                standbyModus = false;
                xAchse = xAchse + auftrag.getBreite() + schneideDurchmesser; //Erweitererbarkeit andere Schneide Durchmesser moeglich
            //TODO:wefwefwefwefwefwef
                yAchse = yAchse + auftrag.getHoehe();
                xAchse = xAchse - auftrag.getBreite();
                yAchse = yAchse - auftrag.getHoehe();
                ressource.setAnzahl(ressource.getAnzahl() - 1);
                //gefahreneStrecke = gefahreneStrecke + auftrag.getBreite() * 2 + auftrag.getHoehe() * 2;
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A side note/tip for the future: programming is done in English for a simple reason which is that any developer in the world should be able to take your code and understand what it does (and a big help comes from naming classes, methods, variables...). The above code _can_ be understood by any developer, but it takes a lot of time because of the names in German and many people (including me in this case) are probably going to give up reading it :)

Comment: This said, I suggest you reduce the code in your question. You can show two empty classes, one holding a List and the other the method where you want to access the List. That's all that is needed to answer your question, all the rest of the code just confuses a potential reader

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor to your `Zuschnitt` class which supplies a reference to your `Verarbeitung` object as a parameter.

For example:

```
public class Zuschnitt {   
    ArrayList<Holz> auftraege;
    ArrayList<Holz> ressourcen;
    
    public Zuschnitt(Verarbeitung verarbeitung){
        ArrayList<Holz> auftraege = verarbeitung.getHolzZuschnittAuftrag();
        ArrayList<Holz> ressourcen = verarbeitung.getHolz();
    }

    ...
}
```

In the actual program, which we do not see here, you will surely create instances of `Verarbeitung` and `Zuschnitt` somewhere. There you create the `Zuschnitt` using `Verarbeitung`

Like this:

```
Verarbeitung verarbeitung = new Verarbeitung();
...
Zuschnitt zuschnitt = new Zuschnitt(verarbeitung);
...
```

This is one of several ways to solve your problem. I hope this helps you with the solution.